# Stripe Connect integration on mobile APP & Api Rest Backend

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native, symfony, stripe-payments

I'm going to try to explain the best that I can. Basically I want to implement **Stripe Connect** to our system, we are building a platform where we have an **API Rest as a backend** (builted with Symfony) & a **mobile app** created with React Native, that's the stack, and my question is ***which would be the best way to integrate Stripe Connect in this stack***? Also I'm having issues following the PHP Stripe tutorials. If just some could guide me a little bit on where should I point would be so greatful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question anybody can answer in any practical way. There is no single "best" way to integrate using Connect, it depends on your business and technical needs. For example are you operating a [marketplace with service providers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide?platform=web) or are you a [payment facilitator](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide)?

The marketplace guide includes a complete example that allows you to [try it out](https://kavholm.com/) and [inspect the code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-demo-connect-kavholm-marketplace).

If you have more specific questions about how to integrate pieces of this in PHP, you should ask those individually.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a complex case to give a proper answer, eatherway thanks a lot for those links, once a get a solution I will post it here so maybe it could help someone!